# Probability - Bayes' Theorem with multiple random variables

Tags: probability, proof-writing, bayes-theorem

I've to prove that following is true:

$$\mathsf P(a,b,c,d)=\mathsf P(b,c)\mathsf P(d|a,b,c)\mathsf P(a|b,c)$$

I've been tried to split or plug some part but I can't get nothing .

Comment: Hint: use the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: I've tried.I know that: P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y|X)
P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y|X)
and
P(Y,Z|X)=P(Y|X)P(Z|X,Y)

Comment: In general $P(B)P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)$. Multiply the first and the third factor of RHS to get $P(a,b,c)$. Then multiply the second factor with this result to get...